# Can you say "In the night?"

Tags: prepositions

Can you say "In the night" to mean during the night, but in a more natural and informal way? for instance, I wake up several times in the night just to use the bathroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find in the night is quite frequently used in conversation, and even in writing. Here are some examples of it being used correctly

> I woke up in the night to use the restroom.
>
> I heard a coyote howling in the night.
>
> The tree branches scratched my windows in the night and woke me up.

These examples provide a good idea of context for using *in the night*. 
It should be noted that *in the night* can **not usually** be used plurally, such as saying

> I woke up in the nights because of a sound.

But you could get away with saying:

> I woke up every night in the nights that preceeded my death.

But it's probably more smooth to write that:

> The difference between 50 minutes and 35 minutes may not seem like much. But it means that, **in the nights** after the full Harvest Moon, you’ll see the moon ascending in the east relatively soon after sunset.

So I would say it's best to stick with using that phrase in **singular** form.

Though I hear it frequently used, some other answers say that **during the night** is better. I tend to use them interchangeably, and find neither to be more correct than the other.

Comment: I don't know that "every night during the nights" is felicitous. (I think "proceeded" might be a typo - do you mean preceded?) Here is a good example of "in the nights" being used well  "The difference between 50 minutes and 35 minutes may not seem like much. But it means that, **in the nights** after the full Harvest Moon, you’ll see the moon ascending in the east relatively soon after sunset." [Shine on, Harvest Moon!, earthsky.org](http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/harvest-moon-2)

Comment: Your answer was useful, but I could not upvote it.

Comment: Is "at nights" OK, too? I got an email from a former professor of English literature, and now a lawyer using it in a sentence. But I got the following answer from a different site:            
"there's no way to use "at nights". Here's the reason:
"At" is the preposition we use before one specific time: "at 5 pm, at noon, at 4:17". That is its use in "at night". "Night" can be used as a time. But "nights" cannot be used as a time."

Answer (score 1):

It is not common. Here we would say

1) "I wake up several times **a** night just to use the bathroom."

Or

2) "I wake up several times **during** the night."

3) "I wake up several time **in the middle of** the night.