# Is it allowed to say "In the night"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I was searching about this and from what I got, people prefer to say "at night" instead of "in the night" as if we say "in the morning" and "in the afternoon"

Related to the title, can we use the phrase " in the night"? In what situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you say "In the night?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158137/can-you-say-in-the-night) Also, https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/178015/9161 might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both expressions but they differ in meaning:

> At or in?
> ***In the night*** usually refers to ***one particular night***; ***at night*** refers to ***any night in general***:
>
> - I was awake *in the night*, thinking about all the things that have happened.
> - ‘It’s not safe to travel *at night*,’ the officer said. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time))

Which is probably why [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20night%2C%20at%20night&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20night%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20night%3B%2Cc0) finds much more instances of ***at night***, than ***in the night***.